# AngularJS factory. I need to call a method in a factory passing in a parameter then I need to retrieve the result from a different controller

Tags: angularjs, http, controller, resources, factory

I am new to AngularJS. I am building an email front-end as a college project.

I have an inbox view that retrieves emails from a json file. It works as expected by making this call: $scope.emails = InboxService.query();.
When the user clicks on an email they are redirected to a new page where I want to view the email, also from a json file (for testing only).

The controller:

```
app.controller('InboxController', function ($scope, $location, InboxService, EmailService) {

//Make call to email by id
$scope.viewEmail = function(emailId)
{
    //DOES NOT WORK
    EmailService.find({id: emailId});

    $location.path('inbox/email/' + emailId);
};

//Make call to inbox
$scope.emails = InboxService.query();
```

});

When the user clicks on an email I want to use the id to retrieve another json file and pass it to a separate controller for a new page.

This is my EmailController:

```
app.controller('EmailController', function ($scope, InboxService, EmailService) {

$scope.emails = {};

//DOES NOT WORK
EmailService.getEmail(function(response){

    $scope.emails.email = response;
});
```

});

This is the email service: DOES NOT WORK

```
app.factory('EmailService', function ($resource) {

var thisEmail = {};

thisEmail.find = function () {

    thisEmail = $resource('json/message/:id.json', {}, {
        get: {method: 'GET', params: {id: '@id'}}
    })
},
    thisEmail.getEmail = function () {

        return thisEmail;

    };
return thisEmail;
```

});

The service does not do what i want. I want to retrieve a json file using an id, then be able to access that file in the EmailController.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
app.factory('EmailService', ['$resource',function ($resource) {

   return $resource('json/message/:id.json', {}, {
        get: {method: 'GET', params: {id: '@id'}}        
    });

}]);
```

In your controller:

```
EmailService.get({id:emailId});
```

You should use the built in state provider https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route
or https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki instead of directly working with the location hash.

Comment: Yes that is a configuration I have used already. It would work if I wanted the result passed back to where I call EmailService.get({id:emailId}); (InboxController) but I need to access the result of this in the EmailController and I don't have an id to pass as a parameter in that controller. In summary I am calling the method with an id from one controller and I need the data in a separate controller.

Comment: Pass the id into the new controller then have the new controller pull the email.
Edit: 
Like so $state.go('email-view', { id: emailId });
OR:
<a ui-sref="email-view({id:emailId})">View Email</a>